# Cannot resolve constructor Intent and ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-arrayadapter

this is my code :

The lines

```
ArrayAdapter<Diseases>(this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
```

and

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
```

showing the errors

> Cannot resolve constructor
>   'ArrayAdapter(com.android.mahanr.healthapp.Tab1, int,
>   java.util.List)'

and

> Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(com.android.mahanr.healthapp.Tab1,
>   java.lang.Class)'

How can I save that with using `getActivity()` instead of `data = DataProviderDiseases.getData();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a fragment , You should use **`getActivity()`** instead of **`this`**.

**Step 1**

```
 ArrayAdapter<Diseases> diseasesArrayAdapter
        = new ArrayAdapter<Diseases>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
ListView listView = (ListView) listView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

**Step 2**

```
 private void displayDetail(Diseases diseases) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(DISEASES_TITLE, diseases.getTitle());
    intent.putExtra(DISEASES_DESC, diseases.getDescription());
    startActivityForResult(intent, DETAIL_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

**Step 3**

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_diseases_main, container, false);

    data = DataProviderDiseases.getData();

    ArrayAdapter<Diseases> diseasesArrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<Diseases>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(diseasesArrayAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Diseases diseases = data.get(position);
            displayDetail(diseases);
        }
    });

     return rootView; // It must be here
}
```

Comment: when i use getActivity() instead of this data = DataProviderDiseases.getData(); shows error Unreachable statement

Comment: i added your code (this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data); still shows error

Comment: @intellij something goes wrong within 3rd step `new ArrayAdapter<Diseases>(this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);` :)

Comment: @StasLelyuk thanks for checking . We should use `getActivity()`

Comment: @MahanRahmati check step 3 .I have modied code .Let me inform .

Answer (score 0):

Any variant of [ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) constructor requires `Context` as a first argument. Please use `getContext()` instead of `this` during initialization of the `ArrayAdapter` instance.